# C# - Json Response to slow (using MVVM)

Tags: c#, json, wpf, mvvm

I want to load a function in the constructor that makes a webservice request, but for some reason the function is not showing, first I will present the code that works (without the request).

**ViewModel - before request**

```
    public FriendsViewModel()
    {                
            au = AuthSingleton.Instance.getAuthUser();
            //this comes from other window
            if(AuthSingleton.Instance.IsAuth == true)
                loadFriends();

    }
    public async void loadFriends()
    {
            ObservableCollection<Friend> friends = new ObservableCollection<Friend>();
            friends.Add(new Friend { name = "Mark", nickname = "Allain"});
            friends.Add(new Friend { name = "Mark", nickname = "Allain" });
            friends.Add(new Friend { name = "Mark", nickname = "Allain" });
            Friends = friends;
      }}
```

**LoginViewModel - after webservice**

```
    public async void loadFriends()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Friend> friends = new ObservableCollection<Friend>();
        var response = await CommunicationWebServices.GetASM("171" + "/friends",au.token);
        var fh = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FriendsHandler>(response);
        foreach (var friend in fh.friends)
        {
            friends.Add(new Friend { name = friend.name, nickname = friend.nickname, date=friend.date });
        }
        Friends = friends;
      }
```

The View is not updating with the webservice, what might be the problem? I've done the debugging and everything is coming back correctly from the webservice.

Comment: Are you sure it's a gui problem? Is your friends still correct/hold the same items?

Comment: I suspect that 2 things might have happened. The first is that you do not raise the PropertyChanged event when you set the Friends property and second might be that the request is not dispatched on the UI thread. I am inclined to think you are not firing the event otherwise you should get an exception.

Comment: @mhttk: the first code worked for him. so the propertychangedevent must be implemented.

Comment: @selmaohneh true, but that could be just because the async method is executed in the same thread of the constructor. If you look at the code, there is nothing compelling the compiler to run the method in a different thread, while in the second snippet the webservice is likely doing it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class FriendsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dispatcher _dispatcher;

    public FriendsViewModel()
    {
        _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        au = AuthSingleton.Instance.getAuthUser();
        //this comes from other window
        if (AuthSingleton.Instance.IsAuth == true) loadFriends();

    }

    public async void loadFriends()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Friend> friends = new ObservableCollection<Friend>();
        var response = await CommunicationWebServices.GetASM("171" + "/friends", au.token);
        var fh = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FriendsHandler>(response);
        foreach (var friend in fh.friends)
        {
            friends.Add(new Friend { name = friend.name, nickname = friend.nickname, date = friend.date });
        }

        Friends = friends;
        _dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged("Friends");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    *** more code here I guess ****
}
```

this should work the way you want. Please note that the event should be raised in the property, but I guess you can see that the issue comes with the different threads?

Comment: it is really interesting, but why OP haven't seen any exceptions?

Comment: first I think the property was not notifying so no chances of seeing an exception, second, even if he was notifying the fact that the async method was defined void and not awaited may have had something to do with it.

Comment: Didn't work. But reading your idea I have another one and just added. OnPropertyChanged("Friends");

Answer (score 0):

Just added `OnPropertyChanged("Friends");` and it worked.